# PHP IOS push notifications issue

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I'm getting the following errors while sending an ios push from my php code :

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file
Warning: stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto

PHP CODE :

$apnsserverurl="ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195";
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cetname);
$fp = stream_socket_client($apnsserverurl, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

Please help

Comment: please check your $cetname file path.

Comment: Yes i have also change the folder & file permission but its still the same.

Comment: with absolute path its the same

Comment: set path your full path directory example: /var/www/html/project/

Comment: its the same, do you think it can be related to the pem file ?

Comment: yes i have check your code everything ok